# Excel VBA IF OR Date Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine if either cell `$H$3` or cell `$H$4` have dates less than todays date then show a userform, otherwise show my shapes if either of these cells equal todays date, for some reason my code works only if both cell `$H$3` and cell `$H$4` have values. Here is my code:

```
Sub textbox96()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("userform")

If (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value < Date) Or IsEmpty(ws.Range("H3").Value) Or _
    (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value < Date) Or IsEmpty(ws.Range("H4").Value) Then
    employeeselection.Show

    ElseIf (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value = Date) Or _
    (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value = Date) Then

        ActiveSheet.Shapes("block").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 96").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 151").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 145").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 133").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 139").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 127").Visible = False

 End If



End Sub
```

Comment: `If ws.Range("H3") < Date Or ws.Range("H4") < Date = "" Then`...

Comment: Wromg way to check for a date a blank cell will also give you true for `ws.Range("H3").Value < Date` You need to also check if the cell is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember a blank cell will also give you a `True` for `If ws.Range("H3") < Date`. So you will have to factor that in

Ex:

```
 If (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value < Date) Or _
    (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value < Date) Then


 End If
```

**Edit**

> @SiddharthRout for some reason my shapes will not hide when i try your code

Did you try it something like this?

```
 If (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value < Date) Or _
    (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value < Date) Then
    '~~> Show userform
    employeeselection.Show
 ElseIf (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value = Date) Or _
        (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value = Date) Then
    '~~> Hide shapes here
 End If
```

> @SiddharthRout your edit is working for me! is there any way add if either $H$3 or $H$4 is blank then employeeselection.show

```
If (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) = 0) Or _
   (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value < Date) Or _
   (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value < Date) Then
    '~~> Show userform
    employeeselection.Show
ElseIf (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H3").Value = Date) Or _
    (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) <> 0 And ws.Range("H4").Value = Date) Then
    '~~> Hide shapes here
End If
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `IsEmpty()`? Especially for the sake of beginner friendlyness and the comprehension of code. `IsEmpty(what)` reads much easier than `if length of a trimmed specific range is not equal to zero` and that's under you know what what those methods even mean.

Comment: @SiddharthRout for some reason my shapes will not hide when i try your code

Comment: @Rawrplus Well using `IsEmpty` can be dicey. Type the formula `=IF(1=1,"","")` in a cell say `H3`. `IsEmpty(Range("H3").Value)` will give you `False` and `?Range("H3").Value > Date` will give you `True` and hence I prefer `Len(Trim())`

Comment: @JoseCortez Can you please edit your question and post the exact code that you are using?

Comment: @JoseCortez I updated my post. you may have to refresh it to see it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout your edit is working for me! is there any way add if either `$H$3` or `$H$4` is blank then `employeeselection.show`

Comment: Yup @JoseCortez But I want you to try it first ;)

Comment: Sid, for the extra effort, +

Comment: @SiddharthRout i edited my code above with my second question, cant get it to work. Thanks for making me at least try lol

Comment: @JoseCortez you are close. check my new edit. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: @SiddharthRout for some reason your new edited code is till bringing up my userform despite todays date being in cell `$H$4`

Comment: @JoseCortez What is the value of H3 ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout the value of `H3` is 08/20/2018, strange tho, i tweaked your code and added a separate `elseif` line that reads `ElseIf (Len(Trim(ws.Range("H3").Value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(ws.Range("H4").Value)) = 0) Then` This edit seems to work correctly

Comment: Ok great :) Whatever condition is satisfied first, the code will stop there

Comment: BRB in 1 hour.. Off to the gym. if there is any other question, will look at it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178406/discussion-between-jose-cortez-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **IsDate** function to resolve the question. If the ws.Range("H4").Value is Null/Empty, the IsDate will return false.

```
  Sub textbox96()

        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set ws = Sheets("userform")
       ' MsgBox IsDate(ws.Range("H3").Value)
' MsgBox IsDate(ws.Range("H4").Value)
 'MsgBox (IsDate(ws.Range("H3").Value) And IsDate(ws.Range("H4").Value))
        'If (IsDate(ws.Range("H3").Value) And (Not IsDate(ws.Range("H4").Value))) Then
            If ws.Range("H3").Value < Date Or (Not IsDate(ws.Range("H4").Value)) Then
                employeeselection.Show
            Else
                If ws.Range("H3").Value >= Date Or (Not IsDate(ws.Range("H4").Value)) Then
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("block").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 96").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 151").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 145").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 133").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 139").Visible = False
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("group 127").Visible = False
                End If
             End If
         'Else
         '  MsgBox "Here"
         'End If
    End Sub
```